# Is it possible to duplicate users on a new Wordpress install?

Tags: users, domain

I have a running site (Site A).

I want to re-write the site fully to improve everything but, when I'm finished, I don't want to have to get everyone to sign up to the new site.

I wondered if I could create an entirely new site on a different domain (Site B) with a clean install of Wordpress - and then when I'm finished developing the site copy over the following tables from Site A to Site B:
wp_options
wp_users
wp_usermeta

And would all my existing users then have full access to Site B (the new site) ?

Or is there more to it than this?

Thanks

Comment: 1st option - Users will able to access the new site because you migrate **wp_users** table. But as it's a different domain, you'll need to configure **home_url** and **site_url** under "wp_options" table. 2nd option, you can just duplicates those tables in a same database with a new "prefix" and connect from a new domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Migrate DB Pro can help with this, make sure to migrate any plugin tables and the WP_Users and WP_Usermeta tables if your users make posts and you want that content to remain assigned an available make sure to keep WP_Posts and WP_Postmeta table as well.

https://deliciousbrains.com/wp-migrate-db-pro/

Also keep in mind that WP uses an EAV (Entity Attribute Value) architecture for pretty much everything User and Content related so if you have a ton of users it will take time or possibly crash.

I run a site with 100K registered users and I have no problems with this process using MigrateDBPro but I know that larger sites would have problems.

Comment: Thanks Nicholas. My site has 232 users so I think it should manage lol. Thanks very much for the great reply :-)

Answer (score 1):

There are several plugins that will export to a CSV file, then import from that file. Your choice on which one to use. Just search via the Add Plugins screen.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can export the tables and import into new database. Of course you need to set proper domain in wp_options table. Or you can use migration plugins.